# МТС Коннект 4G LTE Wi-Fi-модем - номер модели?

Tags: wifi, железо, модемы, устройства

С недавнего времени МТС перестало указывать на своем сайте номера моделей продаваемых устройств. В связи с этим вопрос знатокам: что находится в [чёрной коробке](http://shop.mts.ru/modemy-i-routery/4g-modem/mts-konnekt-4g-lte-wifi-modem.html)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там два варианта, насколько я понял. картинка по ссылке - старая модель. дописал в ответ

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это [МТС 8211F](http://www.shop.mts.ru/support/connect/detail.php?ID=101176936), он же Huawei E8372. Или старый [МТС 825FT](http://www.shop.mts.ru/support/connect/detail.php?ID=101170896) - Huawei E8278. Зависит от того, какой вам в конкретном салоне продадут. На сайте по вашей ссылке - просто генерик коробка.